# "Blue Socket" (WiFi app) installed itself on my computer ?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, malware

Today when I connected with WiFi I got a small Blue Socket window on the bottom right of the screen. I had never heard of this company before.  They are here: http://www.bluesocket.com/
The "wireless solutions" tab on their page says it's a 802.11abg WLAN solution.  I killed the Window - I don't hit 'ok' on any Window that shouldn't be there.  I am running a firewall and antivirus software - and they didn't catch this.

I'm not finding much on this with Google. I tried: "blue socket" wlan (malware OR virus OR trojan)  -"blue socket firewall"
(The last part is because there's a firewall by that name.)

I use this computer daily, and I have not installed any new software or drivers.  I don't see anything named "blue socket" on my computer.  (Search->All files and folders, Task Manager, Add/Remove programs, services, open connections (firewall) ).  This is the first time anything has gotten through my firewall/antivirus software.  I ran a full scan and nothing was found.

I don't have automatic updates enabled.  I do all that manually so I'm on top of everything.

How did this unwelcome guest get on my computer - what is it doing - and how to I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WiFi provider updated it's equipment, and now they use Blue Socket.  It's just a harmless popup window about the connection.  If I click the logout button in the window I really get logged out, and have to log in again.   I added it to my block pop-ups list and now I don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After quickly skimming over their website, they *appear* to be legit.  They have some contact info in the top left corner of [this page.](http://www.bluesocket.com/company)  I suggest giving that number a call.  They also have a "Chat with a Representative" button you may try as an alternative.

Also, if you're worried about malware, the best anti-malware scanner for the windows shell (imo) is MalwareBytes which can be found [here](http://www.bluesocket.com/company).  I've used it on many computers and it always gets the job done.

Comment: I tried the chat.  It's offline.  It's says they'll e-mail me.

Comment: If you're still worried about it, I'd really just get them on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Several Academic and Industrial institutions use BlueSocket WIPS and RADIUS systems, and often bundle in a little 'semi-driver' bloatware in with any automatic setup. My university did this on its wired and wireless systems, before moving to an even worse system (3G ftw!). If I remember it DID appear in the Add/Remove Programs area, so just get rid of it.

Comment: I looked closer in Add/Remove in case there was some word in front of "Blue," and I don't see it.